# How to update a list? No form found worked in my case

Tags: android

I have the following structure, a file. ListActivy extends from java like this:

```
public class Fisc extends ListActivity
```

In this file I do some queries in a SQLite database and create an ArrayList of an object, each record in the database is an object and thus an index in ArrayList ...

```
prog = new Prog();
prog.field = "some string";
progs.add(prog);
```

That done I set an adapter:

```
this.setListAdapter(new ProgsListAdapter(this,progs));
```

Each line will have two of my listview TextView and a ListView listview and within this I have another list.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fisc, null);
    }

    Prog prog = myList.get(position);

    if(prog.size() == 0){
      //I need refresh this ProgsListAdapter create in java file in setAdapter.
     this.notifyDataSetChanged();  //nothing happens
    }

    TextView txTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.time);
    txTime.setText(prog.time);


    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listLines);
    lv.setAdapter(new LinesAdapter(view.getContext(), prog.lines));       
}
```

How would I do that?

The result of this in screen is:

ListActivy item 1 
listview item 1
listview item 2

ListActivy item 2
listview item 1
listview item 2
listview item 3

I need refresh listactiivy itens but this is a custom adapter extends baseAdapter...

thanks.

Comment: I've read this about 10 times and am still confused.

Comment: If you're using db why don't you use SimpleCursorAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

I'm with Muffinbubble.  I don't fully understand the question.

However, it looks like you are trying to nest a ListView (R.id.listLines) inside another ListView (the main one for the ListActivity).  This isn't supported the last time I checked.

You can either look at an [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) to see if it will suit your needs or you will need to manually build the sub-list of items inside the getView() for the main item.

Comment: the application works perfectly the way it is. I found that even if I scroll the screen and it updates everything works as I wanted .. but depending on the user to scroll .... wanted to upgrade without having to scroll the screen: (

Comment: @gerson you can try killing your Adapter (ProgsListAdapter) and creating a new one.

Comment: Ah.  notifyDataSetChanged() should cause the adapter to refresh.  I wouldn't expect to call it within the getView() method of the adapter itself though.  Also, if you want the sub-list to update (still trying to figure out why that works :) ) you'll need to get a reference to the LinesAdapter for the row and call notifyDataSetChanged() on it.

Comment: @Walt My application has a list of times from 04:00 am to 23:59 pm for example. And within hours of each of the first list I have another list of tasks to be accomplished at that particular time. When a task is fulfilled this task is removed from the list of sub-tasks of that time. When all tasks are completed that time I need to update the first list (the schedule) so that the time that has no more tasks to be removed.The problem is that the first list (times) comes with a ListActivy setAdapter and the second list comes from within the adapter (GetView) a (listview) in this XML adapter.